# How to fix Vuejs "uncaught exception: Object" GET Request

Tags: http, vue.js, get, vue-resource, uncaught-exception

I'm doing a GET request to a firebase database and when i console log the data the GET request brings it logs "uncaught exception: Object".

[image: Error Img].

I've already did the POST http request and didn't have any problem, didn't tried any solution as i cant think of one, it doesn't even give me the line of the error.

```
<script>
export default {
    data:() => ({
        blogs:[]
    }),
    methods:{

    },
    created(){
        this.$http.get('https://recetapp-b43f2.firebaseio.com/posts.json').then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

I expect the data showing the actual JSON files instead of the error.

Comment: did you solve the problem ? i have same error , i get data from laravel , but still have `uncaught exception: Object`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
created() {
   this.$http.get("https://recetapp-b43f2.firebaseio.com/posts.json").then(res => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(res.data));
   });
}
```

Comment: Try ```console.log(JSON.parse(res.data));```

Comment: Still getting uncaught exception: Object

Answer (score 0):

[https://recetapp-b43f2.firebaseio.com/posts.jso](https://recetapp-b43f2.firebaseio.com/posts.json)n returns **401** (Unauthorized), so you shall rather catch the this.$http (assume Axios) with:

```
mounted() {
  this.$http.get("https://recetapp-b43f2.firebaseio.com/posts.json")
    .then(response => { console.log(response.data); })
    .catch(e => { console.log(e); })
}
```

Comment: Tried with Axios, didnt got any error but didnt got any data

Comment: There is no data under your link... unless you authorize somehow (Header / Cookie) so you have to capture an exception. Also, move this logic into mounted().